# Invalidating cache based on cache content

Tags: caching, redis

I'm struggling to find a way to invalidate a cache, where cached response contains data that is hidden behind parent entity.

Example:

1. Query "GetUsersInGroup(GroupId=1)" is sent.
2. Response "UserId=1;UserId=2" is then cached & sent back.
3. Some command is issued that should invalidate any data about User, whose id is UserId=1;

How is it possible to invalidate such response, in which we don't know anything about underlying data response?

I tried to include query parameters in my cache key, but to no avail, since i need to know content of cache.

I've read about cache tagging, but don't know how I would implement this in my solution.

PS: I use Redis for caching.